# Certain pages of Jira are continuously refreshing?

Tags: jira

My dash is fine, but when I tab over to "agile" it will not load the content

1. don't think this is a browser issue, because it does the same thing on Safari, Chrome and FF.
2. Another dev was able to log in on my computer and did *not* encounter the same problem.)

http://makeagif.com/i/hV69mv

Not sure if this belongs on StackOverflow but the Atlassian Answers site looks like a graveyard.

Answer (score 0):

Joe,

Sounds like you might have a network issue between your machine and the JIRA server. Are you able to search for issues in the Issues tab?

Also, what makes you think Atlassian Answers looks like a graveyard?

~Matt

Comment: it looks like a graveyard because a lot of the questions are left unanswered

I don't think it s an issue with my machine because I am able to search for issues and another developer was able to log onto my account and sign in without facing the same problem